# Average Number of Answers/Comments per Question by Week

Tags: support, data-explorer

So I have already asked [the question before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279662/average-answer-count-per-question-and-comment-count-per-question-by-week) but my question was phrased confusingly so I was not able to pull the information I was looking for from the mathstackexchange site.

I want to find on a weekly basis, the average number of answers per question. Since most answers on mathstackexchange range from 0-2, I am expecting somewhere around the weekly [average number of answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/edit/491874) per question being somewhere around 1.5.

Here is the previous post again: [Average answer count per question and comment count per question by week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279662/average-answer-count-per-question-and-comment-count-per-question-by-week)

Comment: Rather than ask the same question again when it is originally confusing our wiki-style Q&A permits you to revise your original question to make it clearer.